# Under Linux, How C++ source code becomes executable files or static/dynamic libraries. And how a program get loaded into memory when it runs

Tags: c++, linux, gnu

I know that source code can be compiled and linked to shared/static library or ELF executable files. And when program runs, it loads into memory and creates a process image according to ELF format. But I am not sure how programs loading shared libraries. How a linker looking for symbols in extern libraries and how the .a archive works. What else should I know if program runs on 64 bit OS?

I am trying to draw a whole picture of it. Can someone give a general talk about the whole thing and gives references/documents/llinks so I can study them one by one.

Thanks in advance.

I think my question can be described as:

Under Linux, How C++ source code becomes executable files or static/dynamic libraries. And how a program get loaded into memory when it runs. In GREATE details!

And how many tools I can use to examine/manipulate the Linux binary files(executable files and libraries)? I know some as “nm" "readelf".

Comment: I'm no expert in that area, but you will probably get much better answers if you give a little background about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read:

- the [Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)
- [From Powerup to Bash prompt](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/From-PowerUp-To-Bash-Prompt-HOWTO.html)
- Wikipedia about [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), [Virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), [Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), [Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), [Linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29), [Assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler), [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)
- Levine's book on [Linkers and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)
- [x86-84](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html), notably about the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf%E2%80%8E) specification
- the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book
- several [syscalls(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) man pages, notably [intro(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/intro), [execve(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), [mmap(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap), [fork(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)
- [ELF virus writing howto](http://virus.bartolich.at/virus-writing-HOWTO/_html/index.html)
- [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) (notably internals)
- [Binutils documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/)
- [Program Library Howto](http://www.dwheeler.com/program-library/Program-Library-HOWTO/)
- [Drepper's paper: *how to write shared libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

and good books about Linux kernel & application programming.

Answer (score 2):

Try to real something like this http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/dynamic-linking-linux-and-windows-part-one or this http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463

Answer (score 1):

For a start:

man pages to read:
ld.so, 
ld, 
ar, 
gcc

utilities:
readelf, 
nm, 
ldd, 
objdump, 
c++filt, 
gdb

32 vs 64 bit note: do a readelf -a on 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the same program and diff the output. Note the difference between "Requesting program interpreter" /lib/ld-linux.so.2 vs /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2.