# Do the -Xms and -Xmx flags reserve the machine's resources?

Tags: java, jvm

I know that the `-Xms` flag of JVM process is to allow the JVM process to use a specific amount of memory to initialize its process. And in regard to performance of a Java application, it is often recommended to set the same values to both `-Xms` and `-Xmx` when starting the application, like `-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M`.

I'm curious whether the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` flags mean that the JVM process makes a reservation for the specific amount of memory to prevent other processes in the same machine from using it.

Is this right?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you for editing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Xmx` merely reserves virtual address space.
`Xms` actually allocates (commits) it but does not necessarily prefault it.

How operating systems respond to allocations varies.

Windows does allow you to reserve very large chunks of address space (Xmx) but will not allow overcommit (Xms). The limit is defined by swap + physical. The exception are large pages (which need to be enabled with a group policy setting), which will limit it by physical ram.

Linux behavior is more complicated, it depends on the `vm.overcommit_memory` and related sysctls and various flags passed to the [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#DESCRIPTION) syscall, which to some extent can be controlled by JVM configuration flags. The behavior can range from a) Xms can exceed total ram + swap to b) Xmx is capped by available physical ram.

Comment: interesting... shouldn't `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` prefault the memory when used?

Comment: @Eugene sure, hence the "not necessarily"

Comment: @Eugene awesome! I was looking for `AlwaysPreTouch` without knowing it existed. it explains why my Java process only uses 10 GB of RAM even though when started with an `-Xms` of 200 GB

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: Depends on the OS, though it's definitely a NO in all popular operating systems.

I'll take the example of Linux's memory allocation terminology here.

-Xms and -Xmx specify the minimum and maximum size of JVM heap. These sizes reflect VIRTUAL MEMORY allocations which can be physical mapped to pages in RAM called the RESIDENT SIZE of the process at any time.

When the JVM starts, it'll allocate -Xms amount of virtual memory. This can be mapped to resident memory (physical memory) once you dynamically create more objects on heap. This operation will not require JVM requesting any new allocation from the OS, but will increase you RAM utilization, because those virtual pages will now actually have corresponding physical memory allocation too. However, once your process tries to create more objects on heap after consuming all its Xms allocation on RAM, it has to request the OS for more virtual memory from the OS, which may/may not also be mapped to physical memory later depending on when you need it. The limit for this is your -Xmx allocation.

Note that this is all possible because the memory in linux is shared. So, even if a process allocates memory beforehand, what it gets is virtual memory which is just an addressable contiguous fictional allocation that may or may not be mapped to real physical pages depending on the demand. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803237/794763) for a short description of how memory management works in popular operating systems. [Here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html) is a much detailed (slightly outdated but very useful) information on how Linux's memory management works.

Also note that, these flags only affect heap sizes. The resident memory size that you will see will be larger than the current JVM heap size. More specifically, the memory consumed by a JVM is equals to its HEAP SIZE plus DIRECT MEMORY which reflects things coming from method stacks, native buffer allocations etc.

Answer (score 7):

> Does JVM process makes a reservation for the specific amount of memory?

Yes, the JVM reserves the memory specified by `Xms` at the start and might reserve upto `Xmx` but the reservation need not be in the physical memory, it can also be in the swap. The JVM pages will be swaped in and out of memory as needed.

---

> Why is it recommended to have same value for Xms and Xmx?

Note: Setting `Xms` and `Xmx` is generally recommended for production systems where the machines are dedicated for a single application (or there aren't many applications competing for system resources). This does not generalize it is good everywhere.

**Avoids Heap Size:**

The JVM starts with the heap size specified by the `Xms` value initially. When the heap is exhausted due to allocation of objects by the application. The JVM starts increasing the heap. Each time the JVM increases the heap size it must ask the operating system for additional memory. This is a time consuming operation and results in increased gc pause times and inturn the response times for the requests.

**Applications Behaviour In the Long Run:**

Even though I cannot generalize, many applications over the long run eventually grow to the maximum heap value. This is another reason to start of with maximum memory instead of growing the heap over time and creating unnecessary overhead of heap resize. It is like asking the application to take up the memory at the start itself which it will eventually take.

**Number of GCs:**:

Starting off with small heap sizes results in garbage collection more often. Bigger heap sizes reduce the number of gcs that happen because more memory is available to object allocation. However it must be noted that increased heap sizes increases gc pause times. This is an advantage only if your garbage collection has been tuned properly and the pause times don't increase significantly with increase in heap sizes.

One more reason for doing this is servers generally come with large amounts of memory, So why not use the resources available?

Comment: The `-Xms` is the size of memory which the regions are configured to fit inside. If you have a largely unused tenured space, the actual size faulted can be much smaller.