# Multiple JVMs with sum of -xms greater than host's RAM

Tags: java

Note: I am new to Java (I am a Python dev; the idea of JVM is alien to me)

Say you have a server w/ 8-core 160GB RAM

If you run a Java program with -xms 100G, it would not throw any errors.
What if you run two or more Java programs (multiple JVMs) with -xms -100G?
If memeory permits, its it acceptable to run multiple JVMs on a same host?

Any references would be appreciated!

Comment: Take care--in my experience if multiple java VMs actually go past your machine memory it tends to lead to the entire system thrashing itself until you can't do anything but hit the power switch.  If it's just one VM, I don't think I've ever seen that behavior.  Since we got our 32gb machines at work it's been much better so I haven't seen this in a couple years.

Answer (score 2):

No (sane) OS will give you *actual* memory to back-up your needs, ever heard about `swap space`? And  this is true for python too, memory management is not different, since python still operates with *virtual memory*, right?

If you *really* want your VM's memory to be back-ed up by physical memory, there is flag for that: `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch`, but using it will mean that all the memory that your VM uses has to be zeroed ("touched") and that means it will be a slower start - especially true for such big amounts of memory.

`-Xmx` and `-Xms` are really just start-up flags that tell you the initial memory you want and the max memory you want (usually they have the same value), but that is still *virtual memory* that is being asked from the OS.

Comment: i never had a deep understanding of python's memory usage either. But I've never ran python programs with any memory requirement upfront, hence i didnt know why JVM would require that upfront. So, since -xms worked as virtual memory, java programs wont complain if i run it with -xms that is greater than what's available on the host?  My main concern is that whether the java program will start or not because of the lack of memory in the beginning

Comment: what is point of specifying -xms then if its being worked as virtual memory and it does not reflect onto the availability of physical memory?

Comment: so if i specify 100G of heap memory, how much physical memory is that? does it actually allocate anything in physical memory or is it all virtual?

Comment: @ealeon virtual memory is usually swap + RAM, but different OS probably treat that differently, I guess; there are some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43307880/1059372). I have just tried `-Xms120G` on my mac - and it did not fail, probably it would on windows though... *My main concern is that whether the java program will start or not because of the lack of memory in the beginning* - this heavily depends on the OS and it's configuration, java after all is just a process that requests memory from the host it is running on. You need the OS manual on these things...

Comment: @ealeon btw if I run `java -Xms120G -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` on my mac, it will execute *very* slow and ultimately die with `'java -Xms120G -XX:+AlwaysPreTou…' terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit)`

Answer (score 0):

-xms defines the minimum mandatory requirement for the JVM. At the time of launching the JVM if the memory is available, it will come up without any issues.Same is true for multiple JVM launches as well.
Inshort, as long as minimum memory requirement is getting fulfilled JVM will launch successfully.

http://blog.paulgu.com/java/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap-size/

Comment: so mem defined by -xms is exclusive to each JVM ie if i want two Java programs with 100GB each, i need the host to have 200GB RAM?

Comment: If minimum requirement for both java programs is 100 GB and -xms is set to that, then Yes you would need 200 GB RAM

Comment: Usually you should not keep lower bound so high until very necessary. -xmx should be set to high value, that is the memory your program will consume in worst case.

Comment: Keeping -xms to high value means you are wasting resources ,since that much memory might not be getting used at all