# How much physical memory JVM allocate for its heap?

Tags: java

Follow-up question to [Multiple JVMs with sum of -xms greater than host's RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296903/multiple-jvms-with-sum-of-xms-greater-than-hosts-ram)

My understanding is that JVM -xms 100G does not actually allocate 100G of physical mem but uses virtual memory.

how much physical memory does it actually use to allocate the heap at the start of JVM for -xms 100G?

Comment: That's generally up to the OS unless the application locks pages in physical memory - which is typically not allowed by a process with unelevated privileges.

Comment: You'd need to specify the OS and JVM (+versions) if you want to have an exact answer.

Comment: The JVM doesn't allocate *any* physical memory. It allocates virtual memory. The OS allocates the physical memory.

Comment: okay makes sense. how does the translation of virtual memory to physical memory occur as say, java program creates more objects? JVM understands virtual memory, OS understands physical memroy. I am trying to connect the dots between the two here